# Woocommerce Decline Checkout Process

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

(Theme: Woodmart)

I have one problem, I would like to have a custom meta field in the database of registered users, where I can set his debt and not let him make an order while he has an outstanding debt to the company. The field in the database where the debt will be saved will be pulled from the accounting program and placed in those fields based on the user ID.

I tried to do something but it doesn't work, I just added a meta table, created it manually through SQL, I don't know if I need any other code to make that meta field work, the next code I tried was:

```
<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cssigniter_prevent_checkout_if_user_have_debt' );
function cssigniter_prevent_checkout_if_user_have_debt() {

    //  We check if there is a customer in the database
    $customer = wp_get_current_user();
    $debt = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wp_woocommerce_user_debt' , true );

    if ( ! empty( $customer ) ) {
        $args = array(
            'customer_id' => $customer->ID,
            'wp_woocommerce_user_debt' => $current_user->ID, 'wp_woocommerce_user_debt',
        );

        // Get the data from the column "wp_woocommerce_user_debt"
        $pending_debt = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_woocommerce_user_debt', true );


        // It is checked whether the customer's debt is greater than zero, if so, data is pulled from the table "wp_woocommerce_user_debt"
        if ( count( $pending_debts ) > 0 ) {

            foreach ( $pending_debts as $pending_debt ) {
                array_push( $pending_debt, '<a href="' . $pending_debt->get_meta_data() . '" </a>' );
            }

            // Printing a message to the customer
            $message       = sprintf(
                __( 'Kupovina nije uspjela. Zamolili bi smo Vas da izmirite dug u iznosu od %2$s KM prema kompaniji ... kako bi ste mogli nastaviti kupovati.', 'your-text-domain' )
            );

            wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: you have $customer and trying to get user meta with $current_user->ID ? Then you have $args which i dont see the point of it (there u try again to get user id with $current_user) Then $pending_debt u are trying to get meta with $user_id ?

Comment: "i dont know do i even need to use meta to save "pending_debt" value." If you save the value in user meta then you need to use user meta. I have posted my solution which is assuming your value is in user meta. If not fix it to your needs. Also in your code u are looking for wp_woocommerce_user_debt meta value not pending_debt. So if your meta is named pending_debt change it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function with this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cssigniter_prevent_checkout_if_user_have_debt' );
function cssigniter_prevent_checkout_if_user_have_debt() {

    //Check if current visitor is logged in
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) return;

    // Get User ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $debt = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_woocommerce_user_debt' , true );  

    // Check if user have debt
    if(empty($debt)) return;

    //Print msg if user have debt
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Kupovina nije uspjela. Zamolili bi smo Vas da izmirite dug u iznosu od %2$s KM prema kompaniji %s kako bi ste mogli nastaviti kupovati.','your-text-domain',$debt),'error' );

 
}
```

Comment: it works but can i show amount on this message string..how much debt is

Comment: %2$s i wanted to show how much debt is

Comment: I have updated the notice msg.

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me out with this. All working well.

Comment: Just one question, can i put values in this meta field "wp_woocommerce_user_debt" over woocommerce API or..

Comment: with the api you can create,edit,delete users so yeah

Comment: because its woocommerce API integration..will it work with this "wp_woocommerce_user_debt" column if i make function to store values in that column over woocommerce API..

Comment: you can do it with wp rest api and woo rest api. You should read about both and decide which one is better for you in this case. Both can access users wp-json/wc/v3/customers/ will get all users and so you can loop and find the one you want to edit, Depends on your software how you are going to identify each user.

Comment: thats it..thank you so much once again

Comment: For some reason Woocommerce API didnt read this meta field that i added in user table of wordpress--do i need to do something more to make it visible trough woocommerce API instead of just making column with meta field?

Comment: I would recommend look in to codex and read about rest api and how to register meta and other data in it - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/ Since this is another problem if you get stuck open new question.

Comment: I open new question..
LINK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217234/wont-read-meta-field-in-user-table-of-wordpress-trough-woocommerce-rest-api